# JsonConvert and JArray

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using the Last.FM audio scrobbler to find out what song a user is currently playing:

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getrecenttracks&user=[user]&api_key=[api_key]&limit=1&format=json

However, I am having a problem with formatting. If a user is currently playing a song, the result is formatted as follows:

```
"recenttracks": {
    "track": [{
        "artist": {
            "#text": "Bruno Mars",
            "mbid": "afb680f2-b6eb-4cd7-a70b-a63b25c763d5"
        },
        "name": "Just the Way You Are",
        "streamable": "0",
        "mbid": "39efbdb3-e2f2-4d9f-9f96-53ef364b2d72",
        "album": {
            "#text": "Doo-Wops & Hooligans",
            "mbid": "33030768-eed0-404a-bd5e-af6950546211"
        },
        "url": "http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/Bruno+Mars\/_\/Just+the+Way+You+Are",
        "image": [{
            "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/34s\/98054239.png",
            "size": "small"
        }, {
            "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/64s\/98054239.png",
            "size": "medium"
        }, {
            "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/126\/98054239.png",
            "size": "large"
        }, {
            "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/300x300\/98054239.png",
            "size": "extralarge"
        }],
        "@attr": {
            "nowplaying": "true"
        }
    }],
}
```

I can access the current song with `json["recenttracks"]["track"][0]["name"].ToString()`

However, if a user is not currently playing a song, the API will instead return their last played song... in the following format:

```
"recenttracks": {
    "track": {
        "artist": {
            "#text": "Bruno Mars",
            "mbid": "afb680f2-b6eb-4cd7-a70b-a63b25c763d5"
        },
        "name": "Just the Way You Are",
        "streamable": "0",
        "mbid": "39efbdb3-e2f2-4d9f-9f96-53ef364b2d72",
        "album": {
            "#text": "Doo-Wops & Hooligans",
            "mbid": "33030768-eed0-404a-bd5e-af6950546211"
        },
        "url": "http:\/\/www.last.fm\/music\/Bruno+Mars\/_\/Just+the+Way+You+Are",
        "image": [{
            "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/34s\/98054239.png",
            "size": "small"
        }, {
            "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/64s\/98054239.png",
            "size": "medium"
        }, {
            "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/126\/98054239.png",
            "size": "large"
        }, {
            "#text": "http:\/\/userserve-ak.last.fm\/serve\/300x300\/98054239.png",
            "size": "extralarge"
        }],
        "date": {
            "#text": "25 Jan 2015, 02:21",
            "uts": "1422152473"
        }
    }
}
```

You will notice there is a SLIGHT format change. Instead of track being returned as a simple array `"track": [{}]`, it is instead being returned as `"track": {}`.

This means, in order to access the name of the song, I need to remove the `[0]` from the previously mentioned code.

Is there some way I can program a check to determine which type of code I need to use to retrieve the song name? I have tried both `if (json["recenttracks"]["track"][0] != null)` and `if (json["recenttracks"]["track"].length > 0)`, but neither work.

Comment: You may want to use [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) function

Comment: Doesn't work. JArray does not contain a function for isArray()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to inspect the type of `json["recenttracks"]["track"]`:

```
string name;

if(json["recenttracks"]["track"] is JArray)
{
    name = json["recenttracks"]["tracks"][0]["name"].ToString();
}
else
{
    name = json["recenttracks"]["tracks"]["name"].ToString();
}
```